# Modify a position in a (String, String) variable in Scala

Tags: scala

I have tuple separated by a coma that looks like this:

`("TRN_KEY", "88.330000;1;2")`

I would like to add some more info to the second position.

For example:

I would like to add `;99;99` to the `88.330000;1;2` so that at the end it would look like:

`(TRN_KEY, 88.330000;1;2;99;99)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked great! Although now I have another question.. if this tuple was comming out from a list of tupples, lets say something like this: List((TRN2,88.330000;1;2), (PAY,1;3;4)) how could I modify the first position of this List???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to de-compose your tuple and concat the additional string to the second element:

```
object MyObject {
  val (first, second) = ("TRN_KEY","88.330000;1;2")
  (first, second + ";3;4"))
}
```

Which yields:

```
res0: (String, String) = (TRN_KEY,88.330000;1;2;3;4)
```

Another way to go is copy to tuple with the new value using `Tuple2.copy`, as tuples are immutable by design.

Comment: you should use `+` not  `+=`

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify the data in place as `Tuple2` is immutable.
An option would be to have a `var` and then use the `copy` method.

In Scala due to `structural sharing` this is a rather cheap and fast operation.

```
scala> var tup = ("TRN_KEY","88.330000;1;2")
tup: (String, String) = (TRN_KEY,88.330000;1;2)

scala> tup = tup.copy(_2 = tup._2 + "data")
tup: (String, String) = (TRN_KEY,88.330000;1;2data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked great! Although now I have another question.. if this tuple was comming out from a list of tupples, lets say something like this: List((TRN2,88.330000;1;2), (PAY,1;3;4)) how could I modify the first position of this List???

Comment: ```var myList = ... ;  myList = modify(myList.head) :: myList.tail```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function that gets the job done. It takes a tuple and appends a string to the second element of the tuple.

```
def appendTup(tup:(String, String))(append:String):(String,String) = {
  (tup._1, tup._2 + append)
}
```

Here is some code using it

```
val tup = ("TRN_KEY", "88.330000;1;2")
val tup2 = appendTup(tup)(";99;99")

println(tup2)
```

Here is my output

```
(TRN_KEY,88.330000;1;2;99;99)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make it mutable you could use a case class such as:

```
case class newTup(col1: String, var col2: String)

val rec1 = newTup("TRN_KEY", "88.330000;1;2")

rec1.col2 = rec1.col2 + ";99;99"

rec1
res3: newTup = newTup(TRN_KEY,88.330000;1;2;99;99)
```

But, as mentioned above, it would be better to use .copy